# What do permissible, sin and haram mean?

Tags: halal-haram

What do permissible, sin and haram mean? What are the differences among them? Will you explain them with examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that is permissible is referred to as *halal*.

Something that is forbidden is referred to as *haram*.

Committing a haram action is a sin.

For example, killing someone unjustly is haram. Therefore, if someone does so, they have sinned. Eating pork is haram. Therefore, if someone does so, they have sinned.

However, in cases of necessity, you are allowed to do something haram. For example, if you are stranded on a desert island, and you require food, and pork is the only food available, then you are allowed to consume it, as long as you only eat how much is required.